# Compare two fields updating one of the fields based on result

Tags: sql-server

I have a query with multiple `joins`.  I need to compare a field of one `table` to a field of a second.  If the first field is less than the other I need to overlay the first field with the second field.  Can this be done using a case or if statement? The query extracts data then creates a resultset that has the multiple rows in one row. the  PK is unique_key, linex

Example:

unique_key, line1, person_id, service_date, amount
         unique_key, line2, person_id, service_date, amount
         unique_key, line3, person_id, service_date, amount

```
Select t1.Unique_key, t1.linex, t1.person_id,t1.service_date, t1.amount,     t2.service_date, t2.amount, t3.service_date, t3.amount
  from tbl1   t1
  left join tbl2  t2
    on t1.unique_key = t2.unique_key
  left join tbl3  t3
    on t1.unique_key = t3.unique_key
```

I need to `update` the first service date with the second if the second is greater than the first.

The query is more complex than this.

Comment: What does this mean? `The query extracts data then creates a resultset that has the multiple rows in one row.`

Answer (score 0):

```
case when t2.service_date > t1.service_date 
     then t2.service_date 
     else t1.service_date 
end as service_date
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: The pivot table is

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rename the t1.service_date field:

```
Select t1.Unique_key
, t1.linex
, t1.person_id
, iif(t2.service_date > t1.service_date, t2.service_date, t1.service_date) as [Overlayed_Service_Date] 
, t1.amount
, t2.service_date
, t2.amount
, t3.service_date
, t3.amount 
from tbl1 t1 
left join tbl2 t2 on t1.unique_key = t2.unique_key 
left join tbl3 t3 on t1.unique_key = t3.unique_key
```